# how do i get the ubuntu communitheme in ubuntu budge

Tags: 18.10

i don't like the stock icons that come with Ubuntu budge can install the communitheme form Ubuntu 18.10 i am running Ubuntu budge 18.10

Comment: communitheme (Yaru) is missing all the budgie specific styling.  The GTK elements will obviously work - but the budgie CSS will need to be added.  Nice if someone can help out and add that to Yaru!

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Snap:

```
sudo snap install communitheme
```

#### Using PPA:

At this point of time, Communitheme doesn't have a release file for Cosmic. To install repository of Bionic can be used. For this run:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/communitheme.list
```

Add this line:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/communitheme/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
```

Save file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and press <kbd>Y</kbd>. Then update and install Communitheme using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install ubuntu-communitheme-session
```

This must install the necessary packages. Once the release file for Cosmic is released you can install using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:communitheme/ppa
sudo apt install ubuntu-communitheme-session
```

Since you only need icons, so you can change it from GNOME tweaks.

Comment: when i ram the 2th command i got this                      404  Not Found [my IP]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/communitheme/ppa/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'communitheme' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-communitheme-session
this happened when running the 4th command